# Constructing SymPy rational functions from Scipy filter design

Tags: python, filter, scipy, signal-processing, sympy

Why aren't `num_den_to_sympy(b, a)` and `sy.simplify(sy.expand(tf))` the same? The expanded version contains an additional s ** 4 and I don't know where it came from.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy
from scipy.signal import *
from IPython.display import display

sy.init_printing()

def num_den_to_sympy(num, den, symplify=True):
    s = sy.Symbol('s')
    G = sy.Poly(num, s) / sy.Poly(den, s)
    return sy.simplify(G) if symplify else G

b, a = iirdesign(wp=2 * np.pi * 2.5e3, ws=2 * np.pi * 4.5e3, gpass=1, gstop=26,
                        analog=True, ftype='cheby1', output='ba')

tf = 1
for sos in tf2sos(b, a):
    tf *= num_den_to_sympy(sos[0:3], sos[3:6])

display(num_den_to_sympy(b, a))
display(sy.simplify(sy.expand(tf)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the inconsistent order of coefficients. SciPy orders them from lowest to highest degrees. SymPy's `Poly` constructor expects them to be from highest to lowest: for example,  `Poly([1, 0, 0], s)` is `s**2`

If you reverse the coefficients when using Poly, the two results are identical.

```
G = sy.Poly(num[::-1], s) / sy.Poly(den[::-1], s)
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought something else must be wrong too because the closed loop gain is 10**16 which seems excessive (not that I know much about electronics). Do you know if that value is reasonable?

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea about these things. Perhaps [dsp.se] may be able to help.